# Using Boolean Statements and manipulating original dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-manipulation

So, I've got a dataframe that looks like: [image]

with 308 different ORIGIN_CITY_NAME and 12 different UNIQUE_CARRIER.

I am trying to remove the cities where the number of unique carrier airline is < 5 As such, I performed this function:

[image]

Now, I want i'd like to take this result and manipulate my original data, df in such a way that I can remove the rows where the ORIGIN_CITY_NAME corresponds to being TRUE.

I had an idea in mind which is to use the isin() function or the apply(lambda) function in Python but I'm not familiar how to go about it. Is there a more elegant way to go about this? Thank you!

Comment: show us your (not so) elegant code and we can help

Comment: @0TTT0 The 'not-so-elegant' code doesn't work because I'm trying to use isin() function. But nevertheless, i'd appreciate some of your input if u have any! Thanks

Comment: @misheekoh I think I know what you're after and I've left an answer accordingly.  However, the attempted code helps in several ways.  1. Usually, you're asking a question because you don't understand something.  LIkely, if you don't understand something, you may describe it incorrectly.  As such, provided code then demonstrates your attempts may clarify what you are trying to do.  2. It shows that you are actually trying to do this yourself.  This site runs on people volunteering their time to answer questions.  We generally don't like making an effort for those not willing to make an effort.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you for your input. And yes, I definitely understand that in this community that I'd have to show my effort to what I'm trying to get help with. I'll make sure to provide a better and more concise argument and documentation of my effort in future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`filter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) was made for this

```
df.groubpy('ORIGIN_CITY_NAME').filter(
    lambda d: d.UNIQUE_CARRIER.nunique() >= 5
)
```

---

However, to continue along the vein you were attempting to get results from...

I'd use `map`

```
mask = df.groubpy('ORIGIN_CITY_NAME').UNIQUE_CARRIER.nunique() >= 5

df[df.ORIGIN_CITY_NAME.map(mask)]
```

Or `transform`

```
mask = df.groupby('ORIGIN_CITY_NAME').UNIQUE_CARRIER.transform(
    lambda x: x.nunique() >= 5
)

df[mask]
```